# Order by Key - Objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am trying to query the App Engine Data Store through Objective in Java.

I have stored some dummy data locally buy I can't achieve to get the result ordered by key.

These are the classes:

Parent Class:

```
@Entity
public class Parent
{
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    String type;

    public Parent() {
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
@Entity
@Cache
@Index
public class MainObject
{
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Unindex
    String url;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    Date date;

    @Parent
    @Getter
    @Setter
    Key<Parent> type;

    public MainObject() {

    }
}
```

The thing is that I want to get this query:

```
Key<Parent> parent = Key.create(Parent.class, 1);

MainObjectlastUrl = OfyService.ofy().load().type(MainObject.class).ancestor(parent).order("-key").first().now();
```

This returns null.

```
List<MainObject> list = OfyService.ofy().load().type(MainObject.class).ancestor(parent).order("-key").list();
```

This returns an empty list.

But if I remove the order query, I get all entities.

```
list = OfyService.ofy().load().type(MainObject.class).ancestor(parent).list();
```

Any ideas?

I have checked at Objectify web page, but I couldn't find much.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic Google field that means key is `__key__` (two underscores on each side). This is built in to GAE, so you want `order("-__key__")`.

Objectify could provide an `orderKey(boolean)` method on query to make this slightly more convenient. If you add it to the issue tracker, I'll implement it.

Comment: First, thanks both for answering. This works like a charm.

@elcid the purpose of why I was be able to do this, is because I want to make an auto increment key like SQL through transactional insert.

Thanks!

PS: I am going to add it to the issue tracker

Answer (score 2):

As of Objectify 5.0.1, you can use `orderKey(boolean descending)` instead of `order("__key__")` when sorting by key. See Javadoc at http://static.javadoc.io/com.googlecode.objectify/objectify/5.1.14/com/googlecode/objectify/cmd/SimpleQuery.html#orderKey-boolean-

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is fundamentally wrong. Your desire is to have your query return results ordered by key; the very same thing that uniquely identifies your entity within the datastore. I cannot understand why you would want to do this since the key is derived using the Kind, Id and optionally the parent, if your class has one, as such I can't see how this ordering by key could ever be useful, but I am sure you have your reasons for wanting this. Perhaps you could expand on your question by explaining fully what you're trying to achieve.

Now I will attempt to answer your questions on why your queries aren't returning your desired results and suggest some solutions:

Your first query:

```
MainObjectlastUrl = OfyService.ofy().load().type(MainObject.class).ancestor(parent).order("-key").first().now();
```

The reason this query is returning `null` is because the `key` property you are passing as the condition to the `order` method to sort against is not a field of your `MainObject` entity. It does not exist and will always return `null` when objectify tries to apply the sort order.

The same applies to your second query. It returns an empty list because there are not entities of type `MainObject` with a key field. The only difference to the first query is that you are specifically requesting a list of entities rather than calling `first()`.

The third query

```
list = OfyService.ofy().load().type(MainObject.class).ancestor(parent).list();
```

This query works, of course, because you are querying for all entities of type `MainObject` that are ancestors of specified `parent' entity. Since such entities exist the query returns the expected results.

As you can see, the assumption that an entity's "key" somehow intrinsically exists as a property of your entity is incorrect. In order to use it sort by `Key` you would need to add, say a property `key` to your entity 'MainObject' to hold the value of entity's generated key, which would not make sense and definitely not recommended. 
**Caveat**: there may be a way of getting hold of the key since we know it exists but I am not aware. Perhaps some datastore expert can shed light on this.

I suggest you sort using the indexed properties on your class which make sense within the domain of your application. For example sort by `id`, since it isn't auto-generated and is likely to have some meaning; ditto for the `date` property as they're both likely to have some domain value, as opposed to the `key`. Hope this helps!